# Does the Google Home have any protection against TV advertisements triggering it?

Tags: google-home

Apparently, [lots of Google Home speakers were activated by Google's Super Bowl ad](http://www.theverge.com/2017/2/5/14517314/google-home-super-bowl-ad-2017?utm_campaign=theverge&utm_content=chorus&utm_medium=social&utm_source=twitter):

> Early during tonight’s game, Google’s ad for the Google Home aired on millions of TVs. We’ve actually seen the ad before: loving families at home meeting, hugging, and being welcomed by the Google Assistant. Someone says “OK Google,” and those familiar, colorful lights pop up.
>
> But then my Google Home perked up, confused. “Sorry,” it said. “Something went wrong.” I laughed, because that wasn’t supposed to happen. I wasn’t the only one.

I recently asked about [how you can stop Alexa from being activated by TV presenters](https://iot.stackexchange.com/questions/695/how-can-i-stop-alexa-from-ordering-things-if-it-hears-a-voice-on-tv) and [why Amazon Echos **don't** respond to TV ads](https://iot.stackexchange.com/questions/828/why-doesnt-the-amazon-echo-respond-to-advertisements-or-reports-about-alexa), but this article makes me wonder if Google thought to add the same sort of protections (I suspect the answer is no, but couldn't find any sources to prove it).

**Does the Google Home use any sort of frequency detection or signalling to stop advertisements from triggering the device?**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks like probably not.  I have searched around quite a bit, and I have found a couple pieces of evidence:

#### 1. The article you referenced.

If you read the article again, you will see that the Google Home did pick up the signal - and interpreted it as a wake up call.  Probably the volume and other background noise prevented the signal from being understood, hence, the "Sorry, something went wrong."

#### 2. Google Assistant has retired Personalized Voice Recognition.

It appears that 2015, Personalized Voice Recognition [has been retired](https://www.quora.com/Why-was-Google-Nows-Personalized-voice-recognition-retired-Personalized-Voice-Recognition-setting-is-retired).  This means that Google is basing their recognition off of a larger database of various different accents and dialects, not off of a personalized recognition of your voice in particular.  There is no reason why the voice of the guy on TV should be any different.

---

So as far as I can tell, the answer is,

#### No, for the moment, Google Home can be triggered by advertisements.

Comment: Since the Burger King ad exploit, your answer seems invalid : "not off of a personalized recognition of [somebody's] voice", Google blocked the specific voice of the guy in the ad.