# Why do most smart assistants offer little, if any, customisation of the wake word?

Tags: smart-home, smart-assistants

The majority of *smart assistant* brands, such as the Amazon Echo and Google Home, offer very little in the way of customisation for the wake word (the phrase you use to wake up the device so it listens to you).

For example, [Alexa only offers three choices](https://iot.stackexchange.com/questions/524/how-to-change-the-amazon-echo-wake-word) and Google Home only supports *'OK Google'*. A lot of users seem to be interested in the idea of custom wake words, yet none of the major brands have added support.

**Is there any technical reason for restricting wake word customisation, or is it simply a branding choice?**

I've read about [Google's motivation for using *'OK Google'*](https://blog.google/products/assistant/personal-google-just-you/), which suggests the branding idea might be true, but it also seems that wake word recognition [isn't very accurate](https://www.reddit.com/r/amazonecho/comments/5n23tk/does_your_echo_also_respond_to_the_name_calypso/), perhaps indicating a technical reason. Would anyone be able to clarify which factor is the main reason?

Comment: One thing to remember is that the processing to wake like that must be done in a very low-power, always-on domain -- there's often specialized hardware available for this task in some of the larger SoCs (especially those used in phones), and I assume that the filter coefficients / other parameters are carefully calculated and loaded into that hardware. I forget which SoC Echo runs on, but I imagine there's a similar filter present. The name of the class of algorithms is escaping me at the moment

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Yes there are several reasons.

[This blog](http://lovemyecho.com/2015/11/11/echo-custom-wake-words-why-isnt-this-a-thing-yet/) post explains it about the *Echo* and the wake word *Alexa.* I'll summarize a bit.

Wake word recognition is done [locally and in real-time](https://iot.stackexchange.com/a/367/78). That limits the lengths of the wake word due to obvious processing limitations. Furthermore users don't want to recite a poem to activate the smart assistant. Thus, ***it has to be short.***

It has to work with an almost 100% accuracy when called and also *not recognized* with that certainty when not called for. That makes problems and also makes for a ***minimum length for wake words.*** Amazon's choice to allow *Echo* is quite surprising since it's just two [syllables](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Syllable).

If we look at the usual suspects, we have *Alexa (3 syllables), Amazon (3), Echo (2), Ok Google (4), Hey Cortana (4),* and *Hey Siri (3).* All industry giants almost agree on three being a good choice number of syllables.

Strangely enough the most wanted wake word *"computer"* has also three syllables and would match that requirement easily. It's also not trademarked.

As the blog—and reason—tells us, we totally want to avoid false positives. Let's have a look about how established the words Computer, Siri, Cortana and Alexa are. This is the Google book corpus from 2008.

[image: Ngram computer outshines alexa and siri]

Exactly, Siri and Alexa are virtually flatlining against *computer* and *Cortana* gives an error. Not found. Makes sense since the corpus is from 2008. To give us some more perspective why *computer* is a terrible wake word another graph.

[image: ngram of computer versus other words]

This Ngram shows the two most popular US baby names of 2016 (for currency), as well as Tom and Dave also flatline against *computer*. Queen, basketball and police manage to register properly. Anyhow this gives us an idea why *Computer, Earl Grey, Hot* hasn't been allowed so far. People use the word *computer* way too often.

One more thing about false positives. Alexa rhymes with virtually nothing one would say.

[image: 19 things that rhyme with alexa]

Computer rhymes with 74 things.

Comment: ... and this explains why [Scotty did not get to wake the computer](https://youtu.be/hShY6xZWVGE).

Comment: "I'm going to sex a bird...No not you Alexa!"

Comment: "OK Google"  is four syllables ("oh kay goo gull"), not three, and a lot more than that many phonemes.

Comment: Alexa is a frigging first name... I personally know 2 people with that name, one of which is a cousin. Echo is used as is in my language, And I often say "there's an echo" when there's an echo on the phone or something. And amazon is a river / old tribe's name that a guy in roleplaying like me say relatively often. They really messed this up.

Comment: There's a big difference between a phoneme and a syllable.  "Echo" is 2 syllables, but 3 phonemes (which is still very short).

Comment: I'm not sure I buy that explanation of why the word "computer" wouldn't work.  The word itself is not the only thing being recognized.  Being the first word of an utterance and being followed by a pause are also significant pieces of information that identify the command word.

Comment: @KevinKrumwiede if you take a word that is used so often you still enlarge the risk of false positives. Just a little hesitation before *computer* and it's considered the start of an utterance.

Comment: "Computer" [has now been added as a wake word](https://www.amazon.co.uk/gp/help/customer/display.html?nodeId=201971890). It seems that they've decided it's suitable despite your points, so perhaps they aren't as bad as expected.

Answer (score 3):

> Is there any technical reason for restricting wake word customization

When assistant device is not in use, the application processor (I think ARM in case of Alexa as well as Google Home) is suspended and taken to lowest possible power state. The wake word detection is left to very power efficient DSP which listens to the ambient noise/voices and runs a algorithm to decide if there is a match to the wake word. If it finds a match with good amount of confidence DSP wakes up the ARM core to get going with rest of the processing.

Now since the goal is to be power efficient the DSP in question runs the algorithm as well as stores the template pattern on the on-chip memory rather than the main on-board RAM. This allows system to even take the DDR RAM to lowest power state.

Since the DSP has a number key things to do and very little on-chip memory the Assistant wake words are limited to a few choicest ones that can be matched by the algorithm with high degree of confidence.