# How can I detect Alexa's current state or change its current state with an external device?

Tags: alexa, amazon-echo, hardware

I want to have custom wake-word for Alexa so I want to interface this [Amazon Echo](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00X4WHP5E) with an external device. I am wondering if it is possible to create a proxy device that would wake up Alexa if I give voice command to the proxy device. More precisely it should be able to switch Alexa between its following [states](https://developer.amazon.com/public/solutions/alexa/alexa-voice-service/content/alexa-voice-service-ux-design-guidelines).

> - **Idle**: When Alexa is idle, customers can use the Alexa wake word or a physical control to wake Alexa, which starts her listening state.
> - **Listening**: When Alexa’s microphone(s) have been activated, she is in a listening state and is waiting for voice input.
> - **Microphone Off**: On a voice-initiated implementation, the customer can block Alexa from activating by turning on microphone off
>     mode, which physically powers down the microphones and (if available)
>     camera.

The idea is simple. The device would be capable of recognising words, just some words nothing too difficult.

By default, it would keep Alexa in **Microphone Off** state, so it won't pick up voices from its environment.

Now, when I want to use Alexa, instead of waking it up directly I would use my proxy, that would somehow enable Alexa's microphone and switch Alexa into **Listening** state.

When Alexa goes back to **Idle** the proxy should automatically switch it to **Microphone Off** state.

---

What I need in general are:

1. **The proxy should know Alexa's current state.** Won't be the best solution but I may can decide Alexa's current state using its attention system (its sound and LED signals are summarised [here](https://developer.amazon.com/public/solutions/alexa/alexa-voice-service/content/alexa-voice-service-ux-design-guidelines)). Is there any other way I can know Alexa's current state?
2. **The proxy should be able to switch Alexa into a specific state.** So how can I make Alexa to switch between its states using another device?

It all comes down to what are the possibilities to interface an Amazon Echo / Dot (and Alexa) with another device?

(I am interested in solutions using mechanical interaction as well.)

Comment: Is the [Alexa Voice Remote](https://www.amazon.com/Alexa-Voice-Remote-Amazon-Echo/dp/B01E9AHU8Q) similar to what you want? The push-to-talk works even if the microphone array is off on the Echo.

Comment: @Aurora0001 The purpose is to change the wake-word of Alexa.

Comment: Ah, you're looking for a method which will allow you to use a custom wake-word indirectly? I'll see if I can think of something that'll work then.

Comment: Your question appears to be about (some variation of) the **Echo device** *not* about the **Alexa service** to which it connects.  Consider editing it to clarify, and specify which version of the hardware, ft it has a push-to-talk button, etc.  Alternatively, you could look at accessing Alexa from a customized hardware platform.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[This open source Raspberry PI Alexa client](https://github.com/alexa-pi/AlexaPi) has support for free wake words made as easily from PI's terminal as:

```
sudo systemctl stop AlexaPi.service
sudo nano /etc/opt/AlexaPi/config.yaml

change line:
phrase: "alexa"
```

See [discussion](https://github.com/alexa-pi/AlexaPi/issues/222).